# Среда исполнения Entity Framework

Tags: c#, windows, entity-framework, .net

По причине забывчивости забыл поменять среду исполнения с .net45 на .net40 у нового проекта. У пользователей стоит только 4.0 (Windows 7 по умолчанию). Когда меняешь уже у готового проекта, EntityFramework.dll все равно использует весрию 4.5. При попытке поменять вручную на 4.0 программа не запускается? Есть ли способ решить мою проблему?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Запустить консоль Nuget, и введите команду Update-Package –reinstall

Nuget переустановит все библиотеки, для текущей версии Framework

[image]

Более подробно можно прочитать по [ссылке](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/workflows/reinstalling-packages)

Comment: У меня пишет, что не удается найти параметр -reinstall :(
И у меня нет возможности обновить NuGet, нет прав админа

Comment: Будем считать вопрос решенным. Сделал так: удалил entityframework с помощью NuGet из проекта, установить занова не получалось. Добавил в список ресурсов NuGet'a (В параметрах Диспетчера пакетов -> источники пакетов) локальные ресурсы и установил занова.

Comment: Возможно старая версия Nuget не поддерживает параметр -reinstall